# To remove bullets in a ul class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the bullets in the left module but with no success.
I have created a class for the ul called .menuxxx and then added the below code to my css file although this does not work still. this can be viewed at http://www.safisafihotels.com/testimonials

```
.menuxxx ul{

  list-style:none !important;
  list-style-type:none !important;

}
```

Please guys assist

Answer (score 2):

Your menu (`ul`) has the class `menuxxx`, not its parent.
It should be:

```
ul.menuxxx {
    list-style:none !important;
    list-style-type:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Your css is correct, but are you sure, there is bullets apparing in `ul`?

Answer (score 1):

That is not <strike>bullets</strike>, its *background*:

[image]

```
ul li {
  background: url(../images/style1/bodyli.gif) no-repeat 0px 7px; 
}
```

Remove it, then you can see effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your css selector is incorrect. Since you want to style a specific menu, use:

```
ul.menuxxx {
  list-style:none;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

which will select it properly.

---

As for the `!important` tag, now you have corrected your selector, you can remove it.

---

If, in fact, you wish to *remove* the triangles from the "SAFI SAFI HOTELS" section, since they are generated from the declaration:

```
ul li {
background: url(../images/style1/bodyli.gif) no-repeat 0px 7px;
}
```

and not, in fact, a list styling element, you can remove that from your declaration.

Comment: np. glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bullet (background-image)

```
ul.menuxxx li {
    background: none;
}
```